# Using a Proxy with RestClient in a gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using the gem `nba_stats`, which queries nba.com's stats api. But I need to use a proxy with it and the gem doesn't offer that capability.

Looking through the gem's code, I [see](https://github.com/dagrz/nba_stats/blob/d6fe6cf81f74a2ce7a054aeec5e9db59a6ec42aa/lib/nba_stats/client.rb#L115)

```
@resource ||= RestClient::Resource.new(endpoint)
```

Can I just set `RestClient.proxy` and the gem will use the proxy?

I tried

```
RestClient.proxy = "http://123@proxy.crawlera.com:8010"
play_by_play = client.play_by_play('0021301230')
```

but I get an error

```
URI::InvalidURIError: bad URI(is not URI?): http://123@proxy.crawlera.com:8010
```

I also tried this, with and without the ':', and got the same error.

```
uri = URI.parse("http://proxy.crawlera.com")
uri.port = 8010
uri.user = "83a17a4219d543ef8800965d4293ac5d:"
RestClient.proxy = uri
client = NbaStats::Client.new
play_by_play = client.play_by_play('0021301230')
```

Comment: Proxy is supported in restclient - https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client#proxy

Answer (score 4):

I think your proxy url is not valid, the format should be `http://username:password@example.com/`

Comment: I've tried a few variations on the url with no success. The documentation for the Proxy api says `curl -vx proxy.crawlera.com:8010 -U <API key>: http://httpbin.org/ip` so I believe we use the `api key` as the user? The api key has a colon at the end..  https://doc.scrapinghub.com/crawlera.html

Comment: @Adam12344 Hi, RestClient seems not give us a way to set Proxy authentication, I think you want to try the ruby original HTTP API.

Answer (score 0):

In this configuration, everything works as it should.

```rb
    endpoint = RestClient::Resource.new(url, { proxy: your_proxy })
    endpoint.get(headers)
    endpoint.post(params, headers)
```